# VB.net / VS2017 - Draw lines on a panel inside a custom usercontrol

Tags: vb.net

I figure this is a rather basic question, but I've spent far longer on this than it should have taken.

The Context is the following :

I want to create a custom usercontrol which consists of a panel where 3 lines should be drawn upon it vertically, the control should work in such a way that when the value is changed, the control is redrawn with the updated line positions.

My Code,so far, is the following :

```
Public Class ColourValueBar

Private Position_Marker As Integer = 0
Private Position_Marker_LeftBound As Integer = 0
Private Position_Marker_RightBound As Integer = 0

Private render_Marker As Boolean = True
Private render_Left As Boolean = True
Private render_Right As Boolean = True


Private Shared myPenG As Pen = New Pen(Color.Green, 2)
Private Shared myPenM As Pen = New Pen(Color.Magenta, 4)

Public Property Marker() As Integer
    Get
        Return Position_Marker
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Try
            If (value < 0 Or value > 255) Then
                Throw New Exception("ColourValueBar : Marker " & value & " is out of bounds")
            End If
            Position_Marker = value
            Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LeftBound() As Integer
    Get
        Return Position_Marker_LeftBound
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Try
            If (value < 0 Or value > 255) Then
                Throw New Exception("ColourValueBar : LeftBound " & value & " is out of bounds")
            End If
            Position_Marker_LeftBound = value
            Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Set
End Property

Public Property RightBound() As Integer
    Get
        Return Position_Marker_RightBound
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Try
            If (value < 0 Or value > 255) Then
                Throw New Exception("ColourValueBar : RightBound " & value & " is out of bounds")
            End If
            Position_Marker_RightBound = value
            Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    Try
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.




    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub SetRendering(ByVal marker As Boolean, leftBound As Boolean, rightBound As Boolean)
    Try
        render_Marker = marker
        render_Left = leftBound
        render_Right = rightBound
        Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

'Protected Overridable Sub ColourValueBar_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
Public Sub Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Try
        'Using g As Graphics = PNL_Gradient.CreateGraphics 'Me.CreateGraphics


        If (render_Left) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 56))
        End If

        If (render_Right) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 56))
        End If

        If render_Marker Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenG, New Point(Position_Marker, 0), New Point(Position_Marker, 56))
        End If

        '   PNL_Gradient.Refresh()

        ' End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Sub
```

My testcode in the main form :

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try

        Dim Userbox As ColourValueBar = New ColourValueBar()
        Userbox.Location = New Point(150, 145)
        Userbox.Size = New Size(520, 63)
        Userbox.Visible = True


        Me.Controls.Add(Userbox)

        Userbox.Marker = 155
        Userbox.LeftBound = 100
        Userbox.RightBound = 200
        'Userbox.Draw()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

With the issue being the following :

I can draw the custom control from my main form, and I can see the panel.
Changing the value doesn't seem to do anything and none of my attempts to get the lines to draw seem to work.

Forcing a call of a Draw() sub doesn't display any lines whatsoever, but the code also doesn't throw any errors or exceptions.

I have tried :

- Making a Draw() sub, where I put the code to draw the lines and call it from my main-form
- Trying to overload the Paint() which brings forth warnings of its own

I am also unable to drag and drop my control from the toolbox; with an error message that it "Failed to load toolbox item 'ColourValueBar'. It will be removed from the toolbox' but adding it programmatically to the form seems to work (as far as I know, since the line-drawing doesn't seem to work)

What am I missing, or what am I doing inherently wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Edit :

The edited routine which overrides OnPaint, drawing fine the first time it is laoded, but doesn't update correctly with the line disappearing :

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    Try
        Using g As Graphics = PNL_Gradient.CreateGraphics
```

'MyBase.OnPaint(e)

```
            If (render_Left) Then
                g.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 56))
            End If

            If (render_Right) Then
                g.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 56))
            End If

            If render_Marker Then
                g.DrawLine(myPenG, New Point(Position_Marker, 0), New Point(Position_Marker, 56))
            End If

            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Sub
```

The same routine using the e argument as drawer, which draws the line on the outside boundary container, and updates correctly but has the panel drawn ontop of the lines :

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    Try


        ' MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        If (render_Left) Then

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 56))
        End If

            If (render_Right) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 56))
        End If

            If render_Marker Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenG, New Point(Position_Marker, 0), New Point(Position_Marker, 56))
        End If

        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Sub
```

And the final attempt which works the same way as #2 :

```
   Protected Sub MyPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Try




        If (render_Left) Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_LeftBound, 56))
            End If

            If (render_Right) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenM, New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 0), New Point(Position_Marker_RightBound, 56))
        End If

            If render_Marker Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPenG, New Point(Position_Marker, 0), New Point(Position_Marker, 56))
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint on the Paint event handler.  With the expectation that you never see it break.  So nothing gets painted.  No Handles keyword and no AddHandler statement in the constructor.  You are supposed to override OnPaint() to do this correctly.

Comment: If you want to perform GDI+ drawing on a control from its own code you are supposed to override the `OnPaint` method. It's the `OnPaint` method that raises the `Paint` event, so you need to call `MyBase.OnPaint` either before or after you do your own drawing, depending on whether you want it on top f or below other drawing

Comment: @HansPassant I've overriden OnPaint and now the lines draw fine initially, but as soon as I change the value and it calls a Refresh(), the drawn lines disappear.  I found another way to display the lines succesfully, by adding a "handles Me.Paint" to the Sub which does update succesfully; but the lines are drawn behind the panel instead of ontop, and using jmcilhinney's MyBase.OnPaint doesn't seem to make a difference to the result. I'll update the main post with the two edited routines.

Comment: @Niche What does Refresh() call? Does Refresh() and OnPaint() converge to a single method you can override?

Comment: @workoverflow Refresh calls : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx  Which I'm using as a way to force a redraw when one of the line-related values change.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx : (Invalidate & Update) and (Refresh) are two ways to paint. Using Events like OnPaint does not guarantee that you'll override all events that will cause a redraw. ((Just my 2 cents, I've never dabbled with drawing))

Comment: @workoverflow I've tried Update() instead of Refresh() and then the element wouldn't update anything at all past the first time. It's not quite what I've been looking for.

Comment: alternatively, you could download the VB Powerpacks from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/windows-forms/power-packs-controls which include a Line graphical control that would simplify much of your problem.

Comment: @workoverflow : `Invalidate()`, `Update()` and `Refresh()` are not events. They are methods that causes the control to redraw itself by sending a `WM_PAINT` message to it. When such a message is received the framework calls the `OnPaint()` method because it _**is**_ what takes care of _**all**_ the drawing. Thus overriding `OnPaint()` _**does**_ guarantee that your custom drawing will always be redrawn along with the control.

Comment: If you want to draw on the panel, somewhere in your user control you need to handle the panel's `Paint` event.  It looks like you're doing all the drawing on the user control's surface and the panel gets drawn on top.